# Connect to Windows XP via VMWare

Tags: networking, windows, vmware, windows-xp, vmware-player

Is it possible to connect to the command line on Windows XP running on VMWare, from inside of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to the Windows XP virtual machine via telnet:

1. Set up the telnet server on Windows XP:

   Inside the command prompt of the Windows XP machine run these commands found from here http://seriss.com/rush.102.42/misc/windows-telnet.html

   ```
   sc config TlntSvr start= auto
   sc start TlntSvr
   tlntadmn config sec=-NTLM
   tlntadmn config mode=stream
   ```
2. Get the IP address by running: 
       ipconfig

and note the ip address of the machine in the format `www.xxx.yyy.zzz`.

3. On your Ubuntu machine open up a terminal and type:

   ```
   telnet www.xxx.yyy.zzz 23
   ```

   where `www.xxx.yyy.zzz` is the ip address of your Windows XP machine you noted in step 2. and you will connect to the Windows XP telnet server which will open a `CMD.EXE`for you!

Comment: Good one! Upvoted! (and a free edit)  **;-) :P**